# How i use foreach loop two times in dropdown

Tags: php

I have two dropdown and same array i want to populate same array data on both dropdown
here is code

```php
$selection = array(
                    "Peter"=>"35",
                    "Ben"=>"37",
                    "Joe"=>"43"
                     );

         //first dropdown               
        echo "<select>";
        $option= "Ben";
         foreach($selection as $selection => $value){
            $selected=($option== $selection)? "selected" : "";
            echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$selection.'">'.$value.'</option>';
        }      
        echo "</select>";

     //second dropdown
        echo "<select>";
        $option= "Peter";
         foreach($selection as $selection => $value){
             $selected=($option == $selection)? "selected" : "";
             echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$selection.'">'.$value.'</option>';
        }      
        echo "</select>";
```

Comment: what you actually want??

Comment: first dropdown display all values but Second dropdown is empty

Comment: try to use another name the same name is ambiguous: foreach($selection as $key => $value)

Comment: I want to use same array for all dropdown how can i achieve this without creating another different one array.

Comment: @MuhammadJunaid you don't need to create another array, I wrote a complete answer, please check it. you just need to change the variable which you define inside foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with the name of variable which you define which is the same as array, and it cause problem.

try to use different name in foreach for the key and value:

```
<?php

$selection = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
    //first dropdown               
    echo "<select>";
    $option= "Ben";
     foreach($selection as $key => $value){
        $selected=($option== $key)? "selected" : "";
        echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
    }      
    echo "</select>";

    //second dropdown
    echo "<select>";
    $option= "Peter";
     foreach($selection as $key => $value){
         $selected=($option == $key)? "selected" : "";
         echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
    }      
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using the same variable as `key`. Change it like this

```
foreach($selection as $key => $value) {
            .......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a different name as the key than the name of the array. Reference output:

```
First run:
1 => 2
2 => 3
3 => 4
4 => 5
int(4)
Second run:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /in/uLhFH on line 12
```

Here's the code that generates the output. See comments to understand what actually happens:

```
<?php

// Some key=value pairs.
$a = [ 1 => 2, 2 => 3, 3 => 4, 4 => 5 ];

// Output key=value pairs on first run.
echo "First run:\n";
foreach ($a as $a => $value)
    echo "$a => $value\n";
   
// Beware!
var_dump($a); // int(4)!
   
// This will fail as int(4) is not iterable.
echo "Second run:\n";
foreach ($a as $a => $value)
    echo "$a => $value\n";
```